# Restore IMEI on Android One through Macbook

Tags: applications, rom-flashing, custom-roms, macos, imei

I recently flashed my Android One device & installed a custom ROM on it. I've lost my IMEI number during the process. How can I restore it permanently so that the IMEIs don't get erased on next factory reset?

I'm on Macbook Pro.

PS: Would also like to know for windows on a secondary note.

Comment: You should flash a stock ROM.  It's pretty much impossible to say what any arbitrary custom ROM might be doing incorrectly.

Comment: Would the IMEIs be restored if I did that?

Comment: No guarantees, but they should be.  I had the same issue on one of my devices and it was fixed by flashing the stock ROM.

Comment: Could you please point me to the procedure on how to accomplish that?

Comment: You should do whatever you did to flash the custom ROM, but just use a stock one.  I am not familiar with this particular device or where to get ROMs for it, but you can refer to http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/1465